# Solr find all ids that start with certain path

Tags: solr, solrj

Have a number of id's that look like this:

- /content/myProject/path1
- /content/myProject/path1/page1
- /content/myProject/path2

Now, I want to find all the children of path1, so I do /content/myProject/path1/*.

The problem is that I receive also /content/myProject/path2. How do I make a correct query ?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: What is the definition of the field you're querying? If it's a regular StrField, the latter path should not be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using generic text tokenizer definition. You may want to look at the [PathHierarchyTokinizer](http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/lucene/analysis/path/PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory.html) instead. It's designed to split at the path prefixes. And then, you will not need to do the * at the end.